# engine:wiredTiger in /etc/mongod.conf does not start Mongo DB 3.2 on Centos 7.4

Tags: mongodb, centos7, wiredtiger

I freshly installed Mongo DB 3.2 on Centos 7.4 and below was the configuration

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongo
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
```

I uncomment last line above as `engine: wiredTiger` and restarted the mongodb using command `service mongodb restart`, but Server does not start and gives below error

```
[root@server ~]# service mongod stop
Stopping mongod (via systemctl):        [  OK  ]
[root@server ~]# service mongod start
Starting mongod (via systemctl):  Job for mongod.service failed because the 
control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mongod.service" 
and "journalctl -xe" for details.
                                        [FAILED]
```

When I revert back the changes to original configuration, the server does restart. Any help on how to add `wiredTiger` to the configuration?

> Same procedure worked for another server, but not working for this server